# Azure Service Bus / Function App queue message enqueue / dequeue behavior

Tags: azure

We use Azure Service Bus and Azure Function App components for a software backend operation.
Recently we notice some errors from the App Insights. We noticed some of the Function App operations are started even after passing the message lock end DateTime. Please see the below logs for an example. The operation was triggered on **2/10/2022, 8:46:06.999 AM**, but the queue message lock has ended at **2022-02-10, 08:46:04.5640000Z**.

Has anyone encountered this before and been able to give some insights?

We are using the Standard pricing tier hardware/components, which could be why this is happening.
Thanks in advance.

```
2/10/2022, 8:46:06.999 AM   Trigger Details: MessageId: 9b4759453fab437fa1c995fce5fb928f, SequenceNumber: 8956, DeliveryCount: 1, EnqueuedTimeUtc: 2022-02-10T08:45:34.5480000Z, LockedUntilUtc: 2022-02-10T08:46:04.5640000Z, SessionId: (null)    Information 
2/10/2022, 8:46:06.999 AM   Executing 'Functions....' (Reason='(null)', Id=7e4644f3-9960-4a5e-af58-515b91008a56)
...
2/10/2022, 8:46:07.031 AM   Start processing HTTP request POST ...  Information 
2/10/2022, 8:46:07.031 AM   Sending HTTP request POST ...   Information 
...
2/10/2022, 8:46:07.311 AM   Message processing error (Action=RenewLock, ClientId=MessageReceiver3..., EntityPath=..., Endpoint=...) Error   
2/10/2022, 8:46:07.311 AM       Error   
2/10/2022, 8:46:07.341 AM   Received HTTP response headers after 238.6766ms - 200   Information 
...
2/10/2022, 8:46:07.351 AM   Executed 'Functions....' (Succeeded, Id=7e4644f3-9960-4a5e-af58-515b91008a56, Duration=351ms)
2/10/2022, 8:46:07.872 AM       Error   
2/10/2022, 8:46:07.872 AM   Message processing error (Action=Complete, ClientId=MessageReceiver3..., EntityPath=..., Endpoint=...)  Error   
2/10/2022, 8:46:10.965 AM   Executing 'Functions....' (Reason='(null)', Id=5068f09b-3f74-4d72-a751-6fb8044cfd47)    Information 
2/10/2022, 8:46:10.965 AM   Trigger Details: MessageId: 9b4759453fab437fa1c995fce5fb928f, SequenceNumber: 8956, DeliveryCount: 2, EnqueuedTimeUtc: 2022-02-10T08:45:34.5480000Z, LockedUntilUtc: 2022-02-10T08:46:34.5220000Z, SessionId: (null)    Information 
...
2/10/2022, 8:46:12.363 AM   Sending HTTP request POST ...   Information 
2/10/2022, 8:46:12.363 AM   Start processing HTTP request POST ...  Information 
2/10/2022, 8:46:12.373 AM   FunctionName ended for transaction: { "abc": 111 }  Information 
2/10/2022, 8:46:12.373 AM   Received HTTP response headers after 99.4662ms - 200    Information 
2/10/2022, 8:46:12.373 AM   End processing HTTP request after 99.5389ms - 200   Information 
2/10/2022, 8:46:12.373 AM   Executed 'Functions....' (Succeeded, Id=5068f09b-3f74-4d72-a751-6fb8044cfd47, Duration=1408ms)  Information
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your function has a fairly high [`prefetchCount`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus) and short `MaxLockDuration` while the processing takes some time. Messages prefetched start their clock ticking not at the moment of processing but the moment those were fetched. Trying upping `MaxLockDuration` and tuning `prefetchCount` to get rid of this issue.